# Creating a UInt16 from 2 UInt8s

Tags: swift

In order to illustrate a concept to use later for larger data types like `UInt128`, and `UInt256`, I'm trying to do the following function:

My function takes 2 `UInt8`s, shifts the first (theoretically the more significant bits), to the left 8 and then adds `int2`, (theoretically the lower bits)

```
func combineBits(int1: UInt8, int2: UInt8) -> UInt16 {
   let x: UInt16 = (int1 << 8) + int2
   return x
}
```

Is there something that I need to do to avoid the error: `(int1 << 8) + int2` isn't equal to the specified type `UInt16`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly convert the smaller to the larger type:

```
func combineBits(int1: UInt8, int2: UInt8) -> UInt16 {
    let x: UInt16 = (UInt16(int1) << 8) + UInt16(int2)
    return x
}
```

This also makes the explicit type annotation unnecessary:

```
func combineBits(int1: UInt8, int2: UInt8) -> UInt16 {
    let x = (UInt16(int1) << 8) + UInt16(int2)
    return x
}
```

and it can be shortened to:

```
func combineBits(int1: UInt8, int2: UInt8) -> UInt16 {
    return UInt16(int1) << 8 + UInt16(int2)
}
```

The conversion to the larger type must be done *before* shifting/adding,
which might overflow otherwise.

Comment: Of course in the first example you don't need the explicit type declaration of `x`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I appreciate it

Comment: @ZackShapiro: Did you solve your problem with the Blake2 library?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah. I did

Comment: `[int1, int2].withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt16.self)` produces diff result. Does not seem correct.

Comment: @pronebird: Can you give a concrete example? What are the input values? What is the expected result, and what result do you get?

Comment: @MartinR endianness involved. Flipped int1 and int2 and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun an alternative is using `Data`

```
func combineBits(int1: UInt8, int2: UInt8) -> UInt16 {
    return Data([int2, int1]).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this make the assumption that `UInt16` is big endian? That may not be a safe assumption on all platforms.

Comment: Actually it's the same assumption about the byte order as in the question.

Comment: @vadian I don't think it is, because he's using `+` and not `|`

Comment: @Alexander Well actually there are two different assumptions in this answer (first of which is also in the original question). 1 - `int1` is the lower order bits and `int2` is the high order bits. 2 - `UInt16` is big-endian. That's where this answer has issues on some platforms. The original question doesn't have this issue because the compiler is building the result properly through the initializers and the use of addition so the bits are in the correct order or the platform.

Comment: `combineBits(int1: 1, int2: 0)` as computed in the question gives 256 on all platforms. Your version would return 1 on big-endian, and 256 on little-endian platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do this, in a way that is endian-correct:

```
extension UInt16 {
    init(high: UInt8, low: UInt8) {
        self.init(littleEndian: UInt16(high) << 8 | UInt16(low))
    }
}

let i = UInt16(high: 0xAB, low: 0xCD)
// Represented on Little Endian platforms as 0xABCD
// Represented on    Big Endian platforms as 0xCDAB
```

Here's a more involved, generic solution:

```
protocol PairedUnsignedInteger: UnsignedInteger {
    associatedtype SignedSelf: PairedSignedInteger
}

protocol PairedSignedInteger: SignedInteger {
    associatedtype UnsignedSelf: PairedUnsignedInteger
}



protocol BitPattternInitializable: FixedWidthInteger {
    associatedtype BitPatternSource: FixedWidthInteger
    init(bitPattern: BitPatternSource)
}

protocol UnsignedBitPattternInitializable: BitPattternInitializable, PairedSignedInteger
    where BitPatternSource == UnsignedSelf {}

protocol SignedBitPattternInitializable: BitPattternInitializable, PairedUnsignedInteger
    where BitPatternSource == SignedSelf {}

extension UInt:   PairedUnsignedInteger { typealias   SignedSelf =  Int   }
extension UInt8:  PairedUnsignedInteger { typealias   SignedSelf =  Int8  }
extension UInt16: PairedUnsignedInteger { typealias   SignedSelf =  Int16 }
extension UInt32: PairedUnsignedInteger { typealias   SignedSelf =  Int32 }
extension UInt64: PairedUnsignedInteger { typealias   SignedSelf =  Int64 }
extension  Int:     PairedSignedInteger { typealias UnsignedSelf = UInt   }
extension  Int8:    PairedSignedInteger { typealias UnsignedSelf = UInt8  }
extension  Int16:   PairedSignedInteger { typealias UnsignedSelf = UInt16 }
extension  Int32:   PairedSignedInteger { typealias UnsignedSelf = UInt32 }
extension  Int64:   PairedSignedInteger { typealias UnsignedSelf = UInt64 }

extension UInt:     SignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension UInt8:    SignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension UInt16:   SignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension UInt32:   SignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension UInt64:   SignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension  Int:   UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension  Int8:  UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension  Int16: UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension  Int32: UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {}
extension  Int64: UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {}



protocol UnsignedHalfWidthInitializable: UnsignedInteger, FixedWidthInteger {
    associatedtype UnsignedHalfWidth: FixedWidthInteger
    init(high: UnsignedHalfWidth, low: UnsignedHalfWidth)
}

extension UnsignedHalfWidthInitializable {
    init(high: UnsignedHalfWidth, low: UnsignedHalfWidth) {
        self.init(littleEndian: Self(high) << UnsignedHalfWidth.bitWidth | Self(low))
    }
}

protocol SignedHalfWidthInitializable: UnsignedBitPattternInitializable {
    associatedtype UnsignedHalfWidth: UnsignedInteger, FixedWidthInteger
    init(high: UnsignedHalfWidth, low: UnsignedHalfWidth)
}

extension SignedHalfWidthInitializable {
    init(high: UnsignedHalfWidth, low: UnsignedHalfWidth) {
        let unsignedPromotedHigh = UnsignedSelf(high)
        let unsignedPromotedLow = UnsignedSelf(low)
        let unsignedLittleEndian = unsignedPromotedHigh << UnsignedHalfWidth.bitWidth | unsignedPromotedLow
        let signedLittleEndian = Self.init(bitPattern: unsignedLittleEndian)
        self.init(littleEndian: signedLittleEndian)
    }
}



extension UInt16: UnsignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt8  }
extension UInt32: UnsignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt16 }
extension UInt64: UnsignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt32 }
extension  Int16:   SignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt8  }
extension  Int32:   SignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt16 }
extension  Int64:   SignedHalfWidthInitializable { typealias UnsignedHalfWidth = UInt32 }


assert(UInt16(high: 0x12        as UInt8 ,  low: 0x34           as UInt8 ) == 0x1234                )
assert(UInt32(high: 0x1234      as UInt16,  low: 0x5678         as UInt16) == 0x1234_5678           )
assert(UInt64(high: 0x1234_5678 as UInt32,  low: 0x90AB_CDEF    as UInt32) == 0x1234_5678_90AB_CDEF )
assert( Int16(high: 0x12        as UInt8 ,  low: 0x34           as UInt8 ) == 0x1234                )
assert( Int32(high: 0x1234      as UInt16,  low: 0x5678         as UInt16) == 0x1234_5678           )
assert( Int64(high: 0x1234_5678 as UInt32,  low: 0x90AB_CDEF    as UInt32) == 0x1234_5678_90AB_CDEF )
```

Comment: No, you'll get i==0xABCD on LE, and  i==0xCDAB on BE. The *memory representation* of i would be `CD AB` in either case. – But that is not how I understood the question.

Comment: @MartinR Actually, `i == 0xABCD` in both LE and BE, but the memory representation is what differs (`0xABCD` for LE, `0xCDAB` for BE)

Comment: `UInt16(high) << 8 | UInt16(low)`  is 0xABCD. On BE, this is stored as `AB CD` in memory. `self.init(littleEndian:)` interprets it as a little-endian number, so the result `i` becomes 0xCDAB, which is `CD AB` in memory.

Comment: But anyway, all depends on what OP wants. If `int1` are the "more significant bits" and `int2` the "less significant bits" of the result then it is just `(int1 << 8) + int2`, without any endian tricks. That is how I interpreted the problem. – If `int1` should be stored in the higher memory address and `int2` in the lower memory address of the result, then your (or @vadian's) solution works.